# Different hub brake behavior when standing still and when moving

Tags: brakes

I recently switched to a bike having hub (roller) brakes and hub dynamo, so I am pretty new at this kind of brakes.

[image: brake 1]

[image: brake 2]

I have noticed that if I pull the front brake lever when moving, the brake engages almost immediately, but if I pull the lever when I am standing still the lever goes almost freely until the end of its range before I feel some sort of resistance.

Is this a normal behavior for this type of brakes?

Comment: What kind of hub brake is it?  A coaster brake, a disk brake, a band brake, or a roller brake, or something else?

Comment: @Criggie I have no clue how to tell one from the other... if it helps I'll take a picture and add it here

Comment: @Criggie, comparing images of the various types you mentioned, I think I concluded I have roller brakes. Added that info in the question

Comment: @Criggie, photos added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the behavior got worse, with even a sudden and complete blockage (luckily at low speed), I took the bike at the LBS.

The brake was not properly remounted after a maintenance, removing it and placing it back solved the issue.